# Plot network of nodes and edges on map using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I'm trying to plot a network of locations and connections between them using D3.js. I have two files, "nodes.csv" and "edges.csv" that contain my network information. I'm hoping to get an end result similar to using Gephi's [geolayout](https://gephi.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/map-geocoded-data-with-gephi/) Plugin.

The nodes.csv file is of the following format:

```
+-----+-----+-----------+-------------+
| Id  | ... |    Lat    |     Lon     |
+-----+-----+-----------+-------------+
| 123 | ... | 38.889931 | -77.009003  |
| 145 | ... | 40.730610 | -73.935242  |
| 198 | ... | 34.052235 | -118.243683 |
+-----+-----+-----------+-------------+
```

And edges.csv has the following format:

```
+--------+--------+
| source | target |
+--------+--------+
|    123 |    145 |
|    198 |    165 |
|    198 |    173 |
+--------+--------+
```

I've been able to successfully plot the nodes on a map, but am unsure how to use the source and target values of my edges.csv to reference lines in the nodes. How would I load all the nodes in memory to "look up" start and endpoints for D3 lines? Is it better to convert these CSVs into a JSON format? Any helpful criticism on my working nodes plot is also welcome.

Here's a link to working code with only nodes plotted: http://bl.ocks.org/almsuarez/1173e4cabbcfd032642e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To draw the "linking" lines, here's how I would code it:

```
// grab the edges data
d3.csv("edges.csv", function(error, edges){

  // create a map of our nodes for faster lookups
  var nodesById = d3.map(nodes.data(), function(d){
    return d.key;
  });

  // loop the edges
  edges.forEach(function(d){

    // get pixel coordinates
    var p1 = projection([nodesById.get(d.source).lon, nodesById.get(d.source).lat]),
        p2 = projection([nodesById.get(d.target).lon, nodesById.get(d.target).lat]);

    // append the line
    svg.append("line")
      .attr("x1", p1[0])
      .attr("x2", p2[0])
      .attr("y1", p1[1])
      .attr("y2", p2[1])
      .style("stroke", "steelblue")
  });

});
```

Full working [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/2CrtYy6iRvZxUGee6sog?p=preview).

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you! Now to get tool-tips and circle highlights working on mouseover...